# Search and Highlight the text in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

My search bar is working properly but after I write something in the search input, the text is not getting highlighted.

```
                    <tbody className=''>
                        {onlineUserData
                            ?.filter((onlineUserInfo) => {
                                if (searchTerm === "") {
                                    return onlineUserInfo
                                }
                                else if (
                                    (onlineUserInfo.userName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, `<mark>${''}</mark>`).includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, `<mark>${''}</mark>`))) ||
                                    (onlineUserInfo.userStandard.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''))) ||
                                    (onlineUserInfo.userRole.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''))) ||
                                    (onlineUserInfo.userEmail.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''))) ||
                                    (onlineUserInfo.loginTime.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')))
                                ) {
                                    return onlineUserInfo
                                }
                            })
                            ?.map((onlineUserInfo, index) => (
                                <tr className="" key={index}>
                                    <td className=''>{onlineUserInfo.serialNumber}.</td>
                                    <td className=''>{onlineUserInfo.userName}</td>
                                    <td className=''>{onlineUserInfo.userStandard === "" ? "N/A" : onlineUserInfo.userStandard}</td>
                                    <td className=''>{onlineUserInfo.userRole}</td>
                                    <td className=''>{onlineUserInfo.userEmail}</td>
                                    <td className=''>{onlineUserInfo.loginTime}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                    </tbody>`
```

I used Mark tag in the userName line just to check if it's working or not. But it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You missed $ right before {onlineUserData}.

````
<tbody className=''>
                        ${onlineUserData
                          ?.filter((onlineUserInfo) => {
                            if (searchTerm === '') {
                              return onlineUserInfo;
                            } else if (
                              onlineUserInfo.userName
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .replace(/\s+/g, `<mark>${''}</mark>`)
                                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, `<mark>${''}</mark>`)) ||
                              onlineUserInfo.userStandard
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .replace(/\s+/g, '')
                                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')) ||
                              onlineUserInfo.userRole
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .replace(/\s+/g, '')
                                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')) ||
                              onlineUserInfo.userEmail
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .replace(/\s+/g, '')
                                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')) ||
                              onlineUserInfo.loginTime
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .replace(/\s+/g, '')
                                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                            ) {
                              return onlineUserInfo;
                            }
                          })
                          ?.map((onlineUserInfo, index) => (
                            <tr className="" key={index}>
                              <td className="">{onlineUserInfo.serialNumber}.</td>
                              <td className="">{onlineUserInfo.userName}</td>
                              <td className="">
                                {onlineUserInfo.userStandard === '' ? 'N/A' : onlineUserInfo.userStandard}
                              </td>
                              <td className="">{onlineUserInfo.userRole}</td>
                              <td className="">{onlineUserInfo.userEmail}</td>
                              <td className="">{onlineUserInfo.loginTime}</td>
                            </tr>
                          ))}
                    </tbody>`;

```
````

Comment: No, this isn't working bro